# Can microwave safe glass vessels be used in an electric oven?

Tags: oven, cookware, glass, kitchen-safety

Can microwave safe **glass** vessels be used in an electric oven?
I have this oven: http://www.cromaretail.com/Bajaj-28-Litres-2800TMC-Oven-Toaster-Grill-%28White%29-pc-469-468.aspx

I just checked and found the following written on the manual of the glass ware: http://www.borosil.com/products/consumer/storage/

> SUITABLE FOR CONVENTIONAL OVEN
>   SUITABLE FOR USE OVER FLAME
>   SUITABLE FOR MICROWAVE OVEN

Can it be considered safe (as it says)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes. Basically, this is the same as asking if glass is oven safe:

Generally, glass is oven-safe if taken from room temperature and put in a moderate-temperature, preheated oven. The key thing is to avoid temperature shocks (which will cause the glass to shatter). Some glass is specifically designed for oven use (either by being tempered or made of borosilicate glass). Often glassware will say if it is safe for oven use or not, and under what conditions—check the packaging or instructions it came with.

You also need to take precautions when removing glass from the oven. Do not set it on something that'll conduct heat away rapidly, such as a wet countertop.

Before heating glassware, inspect it for damage. Scratches, chips, etc. make failure much more likely. This applies to the microwave as well.

Note that non-glass parts of microwave-safe glassware may not be oven safe. For example, if it has a plastic lid, that should generally not be used in the oven (even though its OK in the microwave).

### edit:

In response to your update, that oven is what would often be called a toaster or countertop oven. Those change temperature much more rapidly than a larger oven (which can be electric as well). So, generally, you'd avoid glass in them.

But, your glass says it can be used over a flame, from the freezer. So it's clearly one of the very shock-resistant ones, possibly borosilicate. I wouldn't expect it to be a problem. Just make sure to preheat the oven.

Also, since you know who made it, you can of course contact the manufacturer to confirm.

Comment: Derobert, and @TFD have edited the question.

Comment: I have a toaster oven too, it works OK with oven-safe glass. Also, given that the glass container came from borosil.com, I think we can assume that in this case, it is really borosilicate glass, which is confirmed by the "safe over flame" part. I wouldn't have a problem with using this oven with this container, even without contacting the manufacturer.

Comment: Robert, If you edit you answer, or write a comment - you should always write @name, otherwise whom you intend yo talk won't get notifications. `Just make sure to preheat the oven.` every cake recepe asks us to preheat the oven, so...

Comment: @derobert I have a toaster oven too. Borosilicate glass works perfectly in it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they can be used

No, it's not a good idea. It's just too easy to make one small mistake which will result in at least a ruined dish, and at worst case glass shattering into your face

It's not worth the risk. What gain is there in using glass in an oven?

Even glass in the microwave can get so hot that it will crack/explode if put onto a surface with uneven heat (e.g. a single water drop on your work surface)

Comment: Glass has different heat transfer than, say, metal. Its also transparent. E.g., a glass pie pan bakes differently than a metal pan, and has the nice advantage that you can see the crust browning because its transparent.

Comment: In the face of the accepted answer, this one is inadvertently misleading by way of exaggerating the risk. (Borosilicate is designed for boiling sulfuric acid in on an open flame. Soda-lime glass, depends on if it's tempered. Glass is such a complex family of materials generalisations like this are nonsensical.)

Comment: @millimoose Boiling sulphuric acid in a lab is very different from the home kitchen. Kitchen are usually more more casual and lacking in safety equipment. Any glass, borosilicate or not will most likely crack if heated or cooled unevenly, e.g. putting it on a small patch of cold water. Easily tested, and have done it myself more time than I care to remember. I have had tempered glass explode into my face after dropping a spoon on the edge (obviously bad luck, as it hit just the right way onto an existing flaw), but either way, a different material would not have reacted so violently

Answer (score -1):

You can obviously use Borosil containers which is very safe indeed. I make most of the dishes in Oven and Micro oven with Borosil containers.

Thanks-
Joshita